# Screen Size Adaptation | XCode | Swift | iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, screen, resolution

I have been rejected by apple because they want my app to run at full resolution of the device's screen I am running my app on. For Example, I have developed my app for iPhone but it runs in a corner on an iPad.
So, They want to run it on iPad at full screen resolution as it runs on an iPad. Please help me fix this issue, I am in a fix after hearing this issue, Thanks for any help!

Comment: Firstly, have you used the autolayout?

Comment: Is your app universal or iPhone only? An iPhone app must run on an iPad at iPhone 4 resolution; make sure your layout copes with this size device; you can easily deploy your app to an iPad simulator to see what it looks like.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use Auto Layout, I saw them while surfing the internet but no article told about how to apply it....

Answer (score 0):

If you want the iPad app to be exactly as iPhone app... Just set your app in project settings to support only iPhone, it will then fit on iPad automatically. (All iPhone apps are supported automatically on iPad in special compatibility mode)

Comment: Yeah I did that but when I run it, the bottom and right side of the app gets cut out....Any fix for that?

Comment: @user8437669 you need to tell us how you designed your user interface and how you implemented it so we can help you understand what is the problem